# PHP filter using preg_replace to allow only alphanumerics and some punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I have a little problem with `preg_replace`.

I need a function that removes all characters except `[A-z][0-9]` and `.!?`.

I could use `preg_match`, but this only verifies the string, and I want to remove the characters.

This is so I don't end up putting junk characters like `<p>` and `;[[;[p;[`
in the description META tag.

So the function must do this:

`;")<br>kk23?!` → `brkk23?!`

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: i know how to use preg_match ... i don't really fit in with preg_replace for filtering data

Comment: How's that possible? Write the preg_match call that matches the string. Change the word 'match' to 'replace' in the function name. Add a second parameter which is an empty string, what you want to replace the matched characters with. Tada, you've used preg_replace!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
$string = ';")<br>kk23?!'; 
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9.!?]/",'',$string);
echo $new_string;
```

Leaves: letters, numbers, spaces, .!?

---

```
/* 3 choices. Pick one you like! */
$str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9.!? ]/","",$str);
$str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9.!?\s]/","",$str);
$str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9.!?[:space:]]/","",$str);
```

Comment: `ereg_replace()` is deprecated.. `preg_replace()` would be better.

Comment: Thanks Floern. Added a few more solutions.

Comment: i personally prefer preg_match, because i heard that its much safer

Comment: Glad, I was able to help :) Please mark this question as solved if everything looks good ;)

Answer (score 9):

```
 $var=preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9?.!]~','',$var);
```

Don't forget `A-Za-z` and `A-z` are not same

Comment: @RiaD What's the difference between `A-Za-z` and `A-z`?

Comment: @qwerty A-z means "all the characters between A and z in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) You can see for example `\` ` and `[` among them

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just do something similar to:
Just add the characters after the `!`, make sure to escape them if needed.

```
$string = "<br>kk23?!";
$string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \?!]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution will be as below also:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w\.]+$/', $str)) {
    echo 'Str is valid';
} else
    echo 'Str is invalid';
```

// string only contain the a to z , A to Z, 0 to 9 and _ (underscore)

```
\w - matches [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

More visit to this page. I think more people getting the same problem. The better way is to try your self and get what you need. Custom yours or copy paste this php and try it :

```
$sample_input = '&&*9?><<script>}cat-<html>ch(_P.,,mE.:;xc##e*p32t.ion $e){di+-($e->ge69tMesPHP _f0sage()3);}';

$output = ereg_replace("[^..........]", "", $sample_input);        

echo "validate =".$output;
```

modify by filling this to get what you want :

```
 $output = ereg_replace("[^.........]", "", $sample_input);
```

Example : if you want only lowercase then do like this :

```
$output = ereg_replace("[^a-z]", $sample_input);
```

lower case with white space :

```
 $output = ereg_replace("[^a-z ]", $sample_input);
```

and more.....,
This is a simple validation method :

```
$username = ereg_replace("[^A-Z0-9_]", "", $username);
$fullname = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9., ]", "", $fullname);
$city     = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z -]", "", $city);
$phone    = ereg_replace("[^0-9 +()-]", "", $phone);
$state    = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z -]", "", $state);
$zipcode  = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $zipcode);
$country  = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z -]", "", $country);
$gender   = ereg_replace("[^mf]", "", $gender);
```

Try yourself, hope will help...